# How to test Proximity sensor on emulator ?

Tags: android, emulation

This is Code for getting `proximity` sensor.On sensor change i show a `Toast` message.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mSensor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sensor Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (event.values[0] == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Screen off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Screen on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

For the testing this app i connect to the emulator via telnet like this `telnet localhost 5554`. The i change the proximity like this `sensor set proximity 5`. but it doesn't work. What is the wrong thing i did ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, You cannot use proximity sensors on the emulator but you can test them on the real device because they contains that kind of sensors you want to test like accelerometer, gyroscope , magnetometer. But yes you can try gps like application in emulator using DDMS. You can use Genymotion with limited functionality on free version but real devices are advantageous.

Comment: but if change the proximity value as i mentioned above. Proximity value is changed but app is not trigger the event.

Comment: Trust me sometimes they work correctly and sometimes not I've been through that stage where i have to prefer android device instead emulator so reliable medium is only Real Android devices and if you find this helpful accept this as an answer

Comment: That's incredible ridiculous emulator doesn't trigger the event. It was supposed to be the opposite: real sensors less reliable.

Answer (score 5):

This is achievable with following steps:

1. Open `AS`, run the emulator
2. Click on `Extended controls`
3. Choose `Virtual sensors`
4. In upper tab choose `Additional sensors`
5. And there you have it, play with proximity as you want

[image]

Comment: App doesn't properly react with these settings. Using real device everything is fine...

Comment: Looks like proximity sensor is firing onSensorChanged all the time, even without any change. In addition the maximum returned by getMaximumRange is 1.0 in contrast to 10 shown on the emulators virtual sensor screen. This is not really usable for testing.

Answer (score 0):

One solution will be use a third party virtualized android machine like Genymotion .

The application has neat controls to change location data and sensor data , it even has built in java libraries to implement test cases

Comment: actually that feature i can not use coz it is available on commercial version